# How to split list of lists to each list in list to one dictionary using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I currently have this list:

```
a = [[ 'abc=lalalla', 'appa=kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka=oeoeoeo'],[ 'abc=lalalla', 'appa=kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka=oeoeoeo' ],[ 'abc=lalalla', 'appa=kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka=oeoeoeo']]
```

I want to convert it to this dictionary:

```
[{'abc': 'lalalla', 'appa': 'kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka': 'oeoeoeo'},
 {'abc': 'lalalla', 'appa': 'kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka': 'oeoeoeo'},
 {'abc': 'lalalla', 'appa': 'kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka': 'oeoeoeo'}]
```

I have tried using `dict` along with `split`:

```
d = (dict(x.split('=') for s in a for x in s))
```

I am getting only one dictionary because of keys are same so I how can I get every list as one dictionary?

Comment: Please do not do spam tagging: the question does not include`pandas`

Comment: Your code  is invalid python syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [[ 'abc=lalalla', 'appa=kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka=oeoeoeo'],[ 'abc=lalalla', 'appa=kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka=oeoeoeo'],[ 'abc=lalalla', 'appa=kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka=oeoeoeo']]
d = [dict(x.split('=') for x in s) for s in a]
```

Comment: This seems identical to my solution.

Comment: @user3483203, the variables names are different.

Comment: @user3483203 OK~ I didn't noticed that somebody had given out the solution. ^-^

Answer (score 3):

Right now you are using `dict` on a flattened version of your list, but instead you need to use it on each sublist individually after splitting:

```
a = [dict([i.split('=') for i in j]) for j in a]
```

Results in:

```
[{'abc': 'lalalla', 'appa': 'kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka': 'oeoeoeo'},
 {'abc': 'lalalla', 'appa': 'kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka': 'oeoeoeo'},
 {'abc': 'lalalla', 'appa': 'kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka': 'oeoeoeo'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

one. Your list `a` is invalid python syntax.

two. inside each list in `a`, it contains strings so you have to split it by `'='` two get the key and the value.

```
a = [[ 'abc=lalalla', 'appa=kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka=oeoeoeo'],[ 'abc=lalalla', 'appa=kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka=oeoeoeo'],[ 'abc=lalalla', 'appa=kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka=oeoeoeo']]
print(list(map(lambda x: dict(zip([i.split('=')[0] for i in x],[i.split('=')[1] for i in x])),a)))
```

Output:

```
[{'abc': 'lalalla', 'appa': 'kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka': 'oeoeoeo'}, {'abc': 'lalalla', 'appa': 'kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka': 'oeoeoeo'}, {'abc': 'lalalla', 'appa': 'kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka': 'oeoeoeo'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to play around, you can also use `numpy`'s [`np.core.defchararray.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.split.html#numpy.core.defchararray.split) and `dict comprehension`

```
[{k:v for k,v in np.core.defchararray.split(lis,'=')} for lis in a]

[{'abc': 'lalalla', 'appa': 'kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka': 'oeoeoeo'},
 {'abc': 'lalalla', 'appa': 'kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka': 'oeoeoeo'},
 {'abc': 'lalalla', 'appa': 'kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka': 'oeoeoeo'}]
```